# Homebrew slows my terminal down on startup

Tags: macos, terminal.app, homebrew

I've had some issues with my terminal being extremely slow while starting up (both new windows and new tabs), from 10 seconds and up. I've tried deleting the Apple System Logs, but it doesn't help.

Today I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> while it was starting and the following was output:

```
/usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:65:in ``': Interrupt
from /usr/local/Library/Homebrew/global.rb:65
from /usr/local/bin/brew:10:in `require'
from /usr/local/bin/brew:10
```

This obviously makes me think homebrew is doing something fishy that makes things slow down. I get the same message whenever I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> during startup, whether it's after 1 second or 14, so I'm assuming it's the same process that's running for the whole time.

My google searches on this issue came up empty, so I'm throwing it out there and hoping for the best.

Does anyone know how to remedy this?

Comment: The great question would be why homebrew gets started with terminal in first place.

Comment: Start Terminal, enter `cd;open .profile` you will get (hopefully) the TextEdit.app, add `set -x` to the top of the file. Save and open an new Terminal window - you will get what is `bash` doing at the startup...

Comment: I've added "set -x" to my .profile, but I can't see anything different when I'm starting my terminal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. My .bash_profile had about 100 lines like this one:

```
source "`brew --prefix grc`/etc/grc.bashrc"
```

I removed all but one and it's fast and snappy again.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have this line in you bash profile

```
echo 'source "`brew --prefix grc`/etc/grc.bashrc"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

It adds that line every time you open a terminal window.